# retrieve data from server side and display on divs in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a html page that has to display data from the database once loaded, to a number of rows and four columns. i can loop though it with just random data. what i just cant get or even know how to go about is getting data to the webpage. i have read through some interesting finds e.g socket.io, fs but still don't get it.

Below is my code from the client side.

help with an example on how to go about it linking both server side and client side will help a lot.

I am using express js, mongodb, html, css and javascript.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#admin {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 400px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Intro-Inline";
}


/*wrapper for the main container*/

#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}


/*all divs under this container to be maintained in aspect*/

#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px auto;
}


/*div for menu*/

.divmenu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0vh;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid border-color: green;
}


/*css for the body*/

#bodydiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#leftdiv {
  margin-top: 30vh;
  margin-left: 30vh;
  width: 80vh;
  height: 75vh;
  float: left;
  /* border-width: 4px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: yellow;*/
}

.innerdiv {
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 80vh;
  /* height:20vh;*/
  background-color: gray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: black;
}

#tabDiv {
  /* align-content: center;
      align-self:  center;*/
  width: 80vh;
  /* height:20vh;
      background-color: gray;*/
  /*  border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.innertop {
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  width: 34.5vh;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-stretch: extra-expanded;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.innerbottom {
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  width: 35vh;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-stretch: extra-expanded;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 30px;
}


/*div working for contents of music*/

.contentdiv {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 15vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

.arrowdiv {
  width: 8vh;
  height: 19.8vh;
  margin: 0vh;
  line-height: 1vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #131212;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.ccontentdiv {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 15vh;
  line-height: 2vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rcontentdiv {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 15vh;
  line-height: 2vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
  background-color: beige;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgdiv {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}


/*div on mouseover*/

.leftsub {
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}

.popup {
  width: 145px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 50px;
  line-height: 50%;
}

.col1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.col2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.col3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.col4 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  max-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <link href="/css/index.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
  <script src="/javascript/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    var popup = document.createElement('div'); //div
    popup.className = "popup";
    var innercol = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var colone = document.createElement('div'); //div
      var imgcol = document.getElementById("col4");
      var colimg = document.createElement('img');
      colimg.className = "col4";
      colimg.src = "images/blackarrow.png";
      colone.className = innercol[j];
      popup.appendChild(colone);
    }

    popup.appendChild(colimg);

    function multidivs() {
      var columnnames = ["arrowdiv", "contentdiv", "ccontentdiv", "rcontentdiv"]; //styles for innerdiv
      var columnids = ["arrow", "content", "ccontent", "rcontent"];
      var rows = 100;
      var col = 4;
      for (x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className = "innerdiv";

        for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
          var columndiv = document.createElement('div'); //div
          columndiv.className = columnnames[i];
          columndiv.id = columnids[i];
          //  var socket =io();
          //socket.on('content', function(msg){
          //console.log(msg);
          //document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=msg;
          //})

          if (columndiv.className === columnnames[0]) {
            attachImage(columndiv);

          }

          row.appendChild(columndiv);

        }
        document.getElementById('leftdiv').appendChild(row);
      }
      //  alert("total rows"+x);
    }
    //attach arrow image onload and thn on mouseover and mouseout
    function attachImage(columndiv) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.className = "imgdiv";
      img.src = "images/orangearrow.png";
      columndiv.appendChild(img);

      domouseover(); /*this will change the arrow directions and also add popup*/
      domouseout(); /*take out popup*/
      //onmouseover changes the arrow
      function domouseover() {
        columndiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          img.src = "images/whitearrow.png";
          columndiv.appendChild(img);

          columndiv.appendChild(popup);
        });
      }

      function domouseout() {
        columndiv.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
          img.src = "images/orangearrow.png";
          columndiv.removeChild(popup);
        });
      }

    }
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
      <form action="">
        <div id="bodydiv">
          <div id="leftdiv">
            <script type="text/javascript">
              multidivs();
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have added your code to a runnable snippet. I didn't change any logic, but I did insert your JavaScript code into a `<script>` tag in your HTML, so it was runnable. Please review and make sure it depicts your scenario.

Comment: @acdcjunior my scenario is i want data from mongodb to be displayed in the divs on the html page..via the express js.

Answer (score 0):

> basically you want to get the data from server and render it on the client/browser 
>   you should use any httpclient library  .. like AJAX, or axios. to exchange data in json format .

- axios [axios documentation here](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- ajax[ajax examples](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: please can i like have a little scenario with my code....because i cant really grasp the examples......

Comment: let me give this a try first, then will get back to you. thanks